# How to filter based on the previous value and a cutoff value

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook, filtering

[image]I am using Jupiter notebook and I want to create a filter.
I have an array which contains sensor reedings. The sensor dat are available every seconds. I want to implement a filter such as:

> store the last two readings of the SenorData in an empty array
> (FilterData[]),  if the last value (FilterData[-1] ) is bigger than a
> cutoff (500), then use the previous value (FilterData[-2]) and update
> this filtered value to the SenorData  and repeat this loop again with
> the new sensor reading.

Here is an example how my sensor data looks like:

```
SenorData= [110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 110.3244118,
 170.7510605,
 170.7510605,
 2180.280465,
 2417.867061,
 2793.702506,
 2883.198035,
 2822.542497,
 2822.542497,
 2862.483596,
 2862.483596,
 2723.776971,
 2694.70809,
 2812.700278,
 2812.700278,
 2812.700278,
 2596.400342,
 2269.66155,
 1902.867214,
 833.9564196,
 457.4343089,
 160.3366192,
 131.0388501,
 131.0388501,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079,
 91.09775079]
```

Comment: What did you mean `and update this filtered value to the SenorData`?

Comment: Could you please add a desired output of SenorData? What is the rule if the last value isn't bigger than the cutoff?

Comment: I have added an image so the problem would be understood better.

Comment: I have added an image so the problem would be understood better. The sensor data with the yellow circle around it is a noise (as well as the other data above 500). So I want them to have the same value as the sensor data with the rid circle around it. So I want to store the last two readings of the SenorData in an empty array (FilterData[]), if the last value (FilterData[-1] ) is bigger than a cutoff (500), then use the previous value (FilterData[-2]). I dont know if this is the right approach and I also dont know how to do it. If you have any other alternatives would be happy to follow.

Comment: @jason did my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you search for something like this. You us `pd.mask` on your data with the threshold of 500 which results in a Series, where all values greater than 500 are `NaN` now. I'm not sure if you want `ffill()` or `bfill()`. ffill will forward fill the missing values, bfill will backward fill.

**EDIT2** (last one!!! ;) )
I can't get it done with a vectorized pandas method. Since we have to conditionally compare the adjacent value step by step while the adjacent value can change, I think we need a for loop here.

```
def filter_data(data):
    prev = data[0]
    masked_list = [prev]
    for i, val in enumerate(data[1:], 1):
        if val >= 3 * prev:
            masked_list.append(prev)
        else:
            prev = val
            masked_list.append(val)
    return masked_list

result = filter_data(SenorData)
#plt.plot(SenorData, marker='o')
plt.plot(result, marker='o')
```

The list result has the exact same data as the solution of the 1st edit.
Please try it and tell me if that is what you are searching for.

**EDIT**
Apparently you wanted the solution with `ffill()`
Here is the changed solution:

```py
data = pd.Series(SenorData)
filtered_data = data.mask(data.gt(500)).ffill()
print(filtered_data)

plt.plot(filtered_data, marker='o')
plt.grid()
```

filtered data plotted:

[image]

filtered data:

```
0     110.324412
1     110.324412
2     110.324412
3     110.324412
4     110.324412
5     110.324412
6     110.324412
7     170.751060
8     170.751060
9     170.751060
10    170.751060
11    170.751060
12    170.751060
13    170.751060
14    170.751060
15    170.751060
16    170.751060
17    170.751060
18    170.751060
19    170.751060
20    170.751060
21    170.751060
22    170.751060
23    170.751060
24    170.751060
25    170.751060
26    457.434309
27    160.336619
28    131.038850
29    131.038850
30     91.097751
31     91.097751
32     91.097751
33     91.097751
34     91.097751
35     91.097751
36     91.097751
37     91.097751
38     91.097751
39     91.097751
```

**OLD**
same with `bfill()`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(SenorData)
filtered_data = data.mask(data.gt(500)).bfill()
```

filtered_data plotted:

[image]

filtered_data:

```
0     110.324412
1     110.324412
2     110.324412
3     110.324412
4     110.324412
5     110.324412
6     110.324412
7     170.751060
8     170.751060
9     457.434309
10    457.434309
11    457.434309
12    457.434309
13    457.434309
14    457.434309
15    457.434309
16    457.434309
17    457.434309
18    457.434309
19    457.434309
20    457.434309
21    457.434309
22    457.434309
23    457.434309
24    457.434309
25    457.434309
26    457.434309
27    160.336619
28    131.038850
29    131.038850
30     91.097751
31     91.097751
32     91.097751
33     91.097751
34     91.097751
35     91.097751
36     91.097751
37     91.097751
38     91.097751
39     91.097751
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why are the new values all 450. In the filtered values which you have plotted: there are two values which are 170 and after that the values which are 450, I expected them to be 170. I want each value which has a higher value than 500 to have the same value as the previous value.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why i said `bfill()` or `ffill()` . Apparently you want the exact other case i chose. I will edit my answer, you just need to replace `bfill` to `ffill`

Comment: @Jason added what you expected (in the other attempt it takes the value backwards which wasn't higher than 500 and fills all missing value with it. If you check your data, that is the value at index 26). now it checks forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so in this method : filtered_data = data.mask(data.gt(500)).bfill() is there any way to replace 500 with the previous value? What I want to do is: if the current value is 3*higher than the previous value, then use the previous value

Comment: not sure if I get it. Could you please add this testdata: `testdata = [1,2,7,8,12,15,4,3,5,6,20,21,25,2,1,8,9,3]` to your question and show me what the desired output to that list should be ?

Comment: testdata = [1, 1.2, 1, 1.1, 1, 1.4, 4.2, 2.8, 1, 1, 1.2 ]  These are the data set from a sensor which would be available every second. after 5 seconds I would have the data until 1.4 and after this 4.2. Now I want to compere the last value which is available (in this case 4.2) with the previous value (which is 1.4) and if its 2*higher than the previous value, I would replace it with the previous value.

Comment: @Jason Yes, you said that. I just wanted to see if I understand it when you just post the result of that list, but nevermind. I updated my answer already before, did you see it ? Did it work ?

Comment: yess it works, Thats exactly what I had in mind. Thanks for your time.